# How do I access sys.stdin when running a script in PyCharm console mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

This works when I run it in PyCharm (v2020.1) terminal, but when I run it through the console, it just hangs:

```py
#test.py

import sys

txt = sys.stdin
print(txt.read())
```

```py
# readme.txt

random string
```

[image: The run configuration]

Comment: Could you please try to use `Redirect input from` option? It is at the bottom of your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. What if I just wanted to capture a command line argument ? It's weird that my way doesn't produce the intended result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the run configurations dialogue the `Parameters` field is where command line arguments are specified to be passed to the script that can then be accessed using `sys.argv`. To get the input from `sys.stdin` you would use the `Redirect input from` field.

The usual shell [redirection functionalities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) each have their own field (notice they can be different between shells, compare for example with [Windows CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)). With each functionality corresponding to one field, `Redirect input from`, `Before launch` which is equivalent to running a command before redirecting the input, the `Logs` tab for redirecting results to output, etc...

This is convenient for a couple of reasons. First because it gives you the shell syntax in a structured way that dispenses having to write everything on a single line (contrary to writing directly on the command line). Second, because you may be working on a project with developers who use [different shells/OS's](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html) (or want to test different shells yourself) so using the run/configurations dialogue allows to abstract differences in shell syntax and reuse or share the "run configurations" if you want.